# How to declare an array of type of a variable in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics

Suppose I have a variable `x`, which can be any type:

```
let x: number = 5
```

I want to create an array which stores values of type `x`. In this case I want a `number[]`.

However, `x` can be any type: primitives, objects, custom types, etc.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
// Doesn't work
let arr: <x>[] = []
```

I feel like generics is somehow the answer here, but I can't think of any concrete way to solve this.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `let arr: Array<typeof x> = []`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x` is a type name, you just use `x[]` or `Array<x>`. [Handbook link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays)

If `x` is a *variable* name or similar, you use the [`typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator): `(typeof x)[]` or `Array<typeof x>`:

```typescript
declare let x: number;

let arr1: Array<typeof x>;
//  ^^^−−−−−−−−−−−− this is number[]

let arr2: (typeof x)[];
//  ^^^−−−−−−−−−−−− so is this
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=31#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4A8Bc8B2BXAtgEYgwDcAsAFBVKqwwCMWAgjDFAJ4A8yHADiAD2AM3QA+CpQD0U+PAB6iwEhEK1WpXxkACwCWAZ3j6cBYjADaAXSo0U8egCYsACl4CR6AJSXJMuYvnqgUrweoKGBtr6QA)

Note that the TypeScript `typeof` operator **is not** the same as the JavaScript [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator for values. When `typeof` appears as part of a type definition, it's the TypeScript `typeof` type operator; when it appears in relation to a value, it's the JavaScript `typeof` operator.

Comment: As far as I know, in JS `typeof` doesn't work for objects. It simply returns `"object"`. I want some sort of Typescript structural typing check. Is this different in Typescript?

Comment: @EnderShadow8 the `typeof` in TypeScript is different than `typeof` in JavaScript. It's confusing and I think it is a design flaw but it is what it is. `typeof` when used in TypeScript specific code (so, in type annotations, not in run-time code) will do a *type query* and return what the type of some variable is. But when used in its JS meaning (so, in run-time code), it will return the *JavaScript type* of the variable. It's unnecessarily confusing now, because TS re-used the name of existing operator, so it does different stuff based on where it's used.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the replies. I was assuming `typeof` was a JS `typeof` when in fact it being different doesn't actually break JS compatibility.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 - Right, that's why I called out it was the type operato r(not the value operator) above with a link. I should have included a further note saying it's different from the JavaScript `typeof` operator.